# How do i test an exported provider in angular module?

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I need the coverage of this assertion inside app.module but I cannot figure how to test it.

```
export const API_INTERCEPTOR_PROVIDER: Provider = {
  provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
  useExisting: forwardRef(() => ApiInterceptor), // <-- i need to test this line
  multi: true
};

@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [
    API_INTERCEPTOR_PROVIDER,
    ...
```

For now the app.module.spec.ts looks like this

```
//imports ...

describe('AppModule', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [AppModule],
      providers: [{ provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'it-IT' }]
    });
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    const module = TestBed.inject(AppModule);
    expect(module).toBeTruthy();
  });
})
```

Ty in advance

Comment: You have no assertions there. What do you want to test actually?

Comment: TBH its more like testing angular itself, and you dont want to test framework do you?

Comment: Sonarqube and karma say that it need to be tested.. I just removed the export from outside the NgModule and used a `{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ApiInterceptor, multi: true }` inside the providers. No need to test now :)